# How would a huge sexual dimorphism and a short male lifetime of sapient celaphopods affect their society?

Tags: society, underwater, social-norms, gender, sea-creatures

Related to the question: [How could a climate-protection organization breed sapient, tool-developing cooperating Cephalopoda?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/81860/38503)

After breeding several lines of the [Larger Pacific Striped Octopus](http://www.sfgate.com/science/article/Rare-octopus-breeding-in-Alameda-bedroom-4299276.php) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larger_Pacific_striped_octopus)) for several decades in the secret research department of the Private Maritime Research Institute Aveiro, Portugal - which is connected to the Italian-German NGO "Salvare i Mari - Rettet die Meere!" and a couple of opaque companys  financed by Structural and Research Funds (ERDF, ESF and ERC) of the European Union, donations and several economic activities - they succeded breeding two lines of highly cooperative, sapient octopuses which are learning from each other using a [color/sign based language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/66270/how-expressive-is-a-color-based-language) depicted on their skin and using/developing [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/could-underwater-living-organism-create-technology), [advanced tools](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/81689/38503) and even discussing [development of underwater computers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/how-would-an-aquatic-race-develop-computers/) after getting information about human research regarding fluidics.

The scientists observed several big differences to human societies which made the communication pretty difficult as their perception of the world and of society differs quite alot from humans resulting in different directions their logical thinking leads them.

I would like to explore these effects and differences especially regarding their huge sexual dimorphism - females being bigger and having a much longer lifetime than males (which still die after mating, while the females live longer and mate several times).

**What effects and differences would that have in the evolving octopus society?**

Every thought on possible effects on any level of society is welcome. As the effects would certainly differ considering the time after setting free in the ocean it would be nice if you could specify some rough thoughts about the timeline this effect might occur.

Comment: We know nothing about cephalopod society so we are unable to meaningfully talk about how something would affect cephalopod society.

Comment: @sphennings Since the sapient cephalopods are fictional, the question is more along the lines of "how would this particular type of sexual dimorphism influence an alien society?"

Comment: Please note that questions asking "What are the effects of X on society?" are almost universally considered too broad for the site. A society can evolve in infinite ways, based on a variety of factors from environment to conflict to interspecies relations. Create the society you want/need for your story.

Comment: Adding to what @Frostfyre wrote: If you want help with *some specific aspect*, for example to determine whether *a given aspect* of the society you have created *is reasonable in light of other aspects*, then that's what   [reality-check] is all about. Such a question may very well be written to be sufficiently narrowly scoped to be answerable. However, essentially asking us to design a society for these (relatively unknown) creatures is too broad.

Comment: Ah okay thanks - I will work on that!

Comment: This is in the VTR queue, but I cannot vote to reopen it.  It's too broad.  It may always be too broad, but I guarantee that so long as the phrase "Every thought on possible effects on any level of society is welcome" (or anything remotely like it) exists, it's too broad.  Per the [help/on-topic], questions "must be specific and answerable: What problem are you trying to solve?"  This Q isn't a problem looking for a solution, it's what a coworker of mine once described as a solution looking for a problem.